# Why is hibernate deleting rows from join table when adding element to set mapping many-to-many?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Suposse I have two classes:

```
class A {
Set<B> bs
}
class B {
}
```

This mapping:

```
<set name="bs" table="bs_tab" cascade = "save-update">
            <key column="a_id />
            <many-to-many column="b_id" class="B"/>
</set>
```

And join table like this:

```
bs_tab(
a_id, b_id, primary key(a_id, b_id)
)
```

When I add some element to bs set and then call Session.saveOrUpdate(A instance) hibernate is deleting all rows in bs_tab coresponding to B instances that were in the set before adding new element.

How can I solve this?

Comment: <set name="bs" table="bs_tab" cascade = "save-update">
    <key column="a_id />
    <many-to-many column="b_id" class="B"/>
    </set>

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to implement `equals`/`hashCode` correctly. I have the same kind of mapping (unidirectional many-to-many) and adding elements does not generate `DELETE` then `INSERT` SQL statements for the join table.

Comment: That was it. In my equals and hashCode I compared Ids. After I changed it, everything is just fine. Thanks.