# Hibernate many to many association delete on update

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, join

I'm working on a project where I have a Many to Many association in the next way:

```
public class Marca implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "nombre")
        private String nombre;

        @Column(name = "referencia")
        private Long referencia;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "MarcaTipoEquipo", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idMarca") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idTipoEquipo") })
        private Set<TipoEquipo> equipos;
}

public class TipoEquipo implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "equipos")
    private Set<Marca> marcas;

}
```

When I update a Marca object, the records in the join table are deleted where id equals Marca object id.

I've tried adding equals and hashcode methods on the TipoEquipo class as this post [Why is hibernate deleting rows from join table when adding element to set mapping many-to-many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063648/why-is-hibernate-deleting-rows-from-join-table-when-adding-element-to-set-mappin) recommends:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return ((TipoEquipo) obj).getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(this.nombre);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return super.hashCode();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can avoid Hibernate deletes the join table records?

EDIT:

Code to store the data

```
public synchronized Marca actualizar(Marca entity) {
    Long id = entity.getId();
    entity.setId(null);

    Marca marcaAnterior = busquedaGenericaBs.buscarPorId(Marca.class, id);

    marcaAnterior.setIdEstatus(ClaveEstatus.POR_VALIDAR_MODIFICACION
            .getClave());

    entity.setIdEstatus(ClaveEstatus.POR_VALIDAR_MODIFICACION_NUEVO
            .getClave());

    entity.setReferencia(id);

    genericDao.save(entity);

    return genericDao.update(marcaAnterior);
}
```

Comment: why would you set the Id of entity to null? is this the first time save? or update?

Comment: The idea is a bit weird. When a Marca object is modified it's needed to create a new record which references to the original Marca, for that reason I do this:     

entity.setReferencia(id);

The object 'entity' contains the data modified, then I set id to null to indicate Hibernate that save it, then load the oiriginal record from the database and update it.

Let me know if I'm not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Is 'Marca boject id' the primary key? **usually you don't modify the primarykey**, if you do so, then you can expect the related data to be removed(if Cascade=all). I'd suggest you pull the child collections(Eager load) when you are trying to update the Marca object Id and save it to the db again with new id. (ofcourse you have to delete the data with old primary key before you save this)

Comment: Yes Marca object has an identity primary key but the Id is not modified when I update the object, other attributes are update. I edit the answer to include the whole Marca class.

Comment: You may try to set the joincolumn and inversjoincolumn attributes to updatable,nullable = false. http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: It doesn't help. Anyway I think this could avoid to modifiy when I really want to modify a Marca object.

Comment: Yeah, it helps you to not include the join table when updating. You said, it is not working? meaning the data in the join table is still deleting? Could you post the code  whre you store the data?

Comment: Yes, the data in the join table is still deleting, I edit the question to add the code where I store the data.