# How to update link table in Hibernate ManyToMany Mapping

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a Hibernate ManyToMany mapping between data table and user table linked by data_user table. Now I want to update the data table to add one more user to the data. How to update link table(data_user) to add one more entry for the new user?

I, first updated the user collection: `data.getUsers().add(user)`, and then in the DAO layer tried `session.saveOrUpdate(data)`. But it deleted everything in the link table.

---

**Update1**:  data_user(iddata_user,iddataroom,iduser) was manually created in the db.

**Update2** : implemented Hashcode and equals for Data and User.

**Update 3**: I changed to `CascadeType.MERGE`. This updates my link table. Also, I am never going to update User table from Data which hibernate was trying when CascadeType was ALL.

> org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the
>   same identifier value was already associated with the session.

PS: I am very new to hibernate.

```
public class Data {
    private int dataId;
    private Data parentData;
    private Set<User> users;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "data_user", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "iddata") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "iduser") })
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you need to show us more of the code/schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override equals() and hashCode() in your entities or you are going to run into issues sooner or latter see [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode) for more details.

If your problem still exists after overriding equals() and hashCode() you may add a mappedBy  on the other side of the relation see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438531/hibernate-4-1-2-and-spring-3-1-2-manytomany-relationship-does-not-store-re) for more details.

Comment: hmm, but this seems to be 1 or 2 step ahead. I am trying to do basics first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063648/why-is-hibernate-deleting-rows-from-join-table-when-adding-element-to-set-mappin

Comment: if you want to compare your objects or add them to a Set or Map then you must implement equals and hashCode read [this](http://www.laliluna.de/jpa-hibernate-guide/ch06s06.html) and [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode.html)

Comment: @karimmohsen thanks, I progressed a bit. But ran into this issue:
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Comment: @karimmohsen can you help me to understand CascadeType? I will then accept your answer :-P

Comment: @Formohit `“cascade=CascadeType.ALL”` and it essentially means that any change happened on DataRoom  Entity must cascade to User entity as well. If you save a Dataroom, then all associated users will also be saved into database. If you delete a Dataroom then all users associated with that Employee also be deleted. for furhter info see [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/09/25/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/) link

Comment: @Formohit for org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException see [this](http://kousikraj.me/2010/12/31/hibernate-non-unique-object-exception/) link i think you are making the same mistake.